# How to spread a current spike?

Tags: power-supply, current-limiting

I have a 12V circuit powered by a 'smart' power supply feeding two USB sockets (similar to [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08TMDTQQV)). The two sockets are parallel to each other and in series with a simple switch.

[image]

Whenever I flick the switch on, the supply's short circuit protection is triggered.[a] The supply stops providing current for 10 seconds and then turns back on. This doesn't happen when I connect only either of the sockets or when I connect them one after other.

My theory is that the sockets contain some largish capacitors[b] that, when connected simultaneously, simply pull too much current for a brief moment triggering the protection.

If the switch is left on throughout the 10s period the protection doesn't trigger again - the supply just returns to normal operation. I assume that this is because when the supply restarts it has some kind of ramp-up period that is just enough for the capacitors to charge while slow enough not to trigger the protection.

Anyway, due to physical constraints I can't add another switch to power up each socket individually. Is there some component I could insert somewhere into the circuit that would prevent the protection from triggering?

Unfortunately I don't know what is the current threshold for the protection to trigger. What I do know is that each socket is rated 40 W meaning that together they must be able to pull ~7 A continuously.

[a] The supply signals this on its display.
[b] I deduce this from the several seconds its display stays on after disconnecting it from power.

Comment: You're probably right about your assumptions. Have you tried placing a largish capacitor (100uF to 1000uF) just before the switch? That may prevent the power supply from tripping as the capacitor will supply the brunt of the current at turn on. Your switch contacts may start pitting.  Or, choose a different power supply that will supply constant current during overload conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer:

Use an NTC metal oxide **Inrush Current Limiter, ICL**

It appears the output is switched on without a soft start, so your surge current depends on the capacitance of each load and the associated loop ESR.

Thus **Ipk= 5V/ESRc=  C * dV/dt** is my best guess that with two loads the Ipk*t duration is integrated to trip OCP.

Thus **dV/dt = 5V/ESR*C** is too fast for your supply with two loads.

Since you can't easily modify the loads or source, one alternative is to insert ICL's for the desired current limit.  You may have to get a few values to see what works with every combination of two devices connected that you have. But something in the 1 ohm R25 range will protect it. For other characteristics like operating temperature , you want to choose one with the highest R25'C resistance but also the highest current rating > 7A.

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/inrush-current-limiters-icl/151?s=N4IgjCBcoGwOwE4qgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iHAHQCsABAIIjE0AcTLIHzxb1AZk59qAFmHc6E-ggmzmAXWIAHAC5QQAVQB2AS1UB5dAFl8mXAFcATvhABfYmARsk0EGkhY8RUhRAAGECUQNQ0AZVUrXW0Ac3sHEAAmP10UbCDiGGQQXQATDQBaMH8IFXVIEC5VAE9lWwrzNDs7IA

Comment: Beat me to it.  We used these for a PoE switch that was tripping overcurrent protection to charge its power supply caps up.  Be warned that they will get warm/hot during normal operation so make room for them.

Comment: If operated near limit they will range from 85'C to 125'C, so choosing a higher limit is 1st priority and choosing a higher R25 2nd. Otherwise, you need an active current limit  a FET. If there is contact bounce, with the2nd, there may be false trips when hot as there is no cool down time delay like PC PSU's use

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your answer! I have only basic knowledge in EE so I wasn't able to follow your calculations. Where does the `5V` comes from?

However, I now know what NTCs are. If I understand it right, an NTC has to operate at high temperature to be effective. I.e. if its operating temperature would be as low as eg. 50 C then if the ambient temperature would raise to 50 the NTC wouldn't protect against the surge. Right?

Comment: I believe @TonyStewartEE75 meant to use 12V but the principle remains the same, and so does the solution.  At the risk of rehashing what you've already learned, ICLs are a special subset of NTC thermistors that are self-heating, but the thermistor material doesn't care where the heat comes from so yes, operating them in elevated temperatures could reduce performance.  I'd use Tony's recommendation as a starting point and get a few different resistances to try out.  I doubt it, but the USB sockets could have some sort of undervoltage lockout that might not play well with the ICL's resistance.